# Receiver to Alarm Activity bundle returning null, even with default bundle values assigned

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bundle

I am trying to pass to strings from a broadcast receiver to an alarm activity but I keep getting a null pointer exception.

I checked the value in the broadcast receiver and the string that is being bundled with the alarm intent is not null.

I am attaching the strings to the intent and starting the alarm activity intent like this:

```
@Override    
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent normalReminderIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ReminderAlarmActivity.class);

    // Bundle information and add to the intent for use in the alarm notification
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("Title", title);
    extras.putString("Description", description);
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    // Start the reminder activity
    context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(normalReminderIntent);
}
```

Then in the alarm activity I did the intent get extras and even set a default value but I am still getting null pointer. I am doing it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dialog);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.alarm_activity_reminder);

    // Get the bundled info for title and description
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String title = (String) intent.getExtras().getString("Title", "");
    String description = (String) intent.getExtras().getString("Description", "");
}
```

Looking at the getString method I can't understand why I would get a null pointer, and not the default value:

```
public String getString(String key, String defaultValue) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```

And after searching many questions on here I am not sure why I am getting a null pointer in general.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: check the answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `normalReminderIntent.putExtras` instead of `intent.putExtras` in onReceive

Comment: Awesome can't believe I missed that

Comment: Thanks very much it won't let me mark as answer for 5 mins but I am sure that is what it is. Thanks!